# Referencing scripts installed with npm in ASP.NET Core view

Tags: asp.net, npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been using `npm` on my front-end React app and I simply reference it as below:

```
import React from 'react';
```

How do I reference a `js` file installed with `npm` in an ASP.NET Core view? The file is under `node_modules/{package-name}` folder.

Do I need to manually copy a file to my `scripts` or `lib` folder?